# ¿Como crear un servidor básico, servirle CSS y JavaScript en nodeJS?

Tags: nodejs

Estoy creando un servidor en `node.js`, con los siguientes elementos:

```
Carpeta
    index.html
    js.js
    css.css
```

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
<body>
<h1> Mi  Primer  Web  Node </h1>
</body>
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
alert("Soy javascript");
```

**CSS**:

```
body {
    background-color: blue;
}

h1 {
    color:red;
}
```

**Usando el siguiente codigo:**

**createServer.js:**

```
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

http.createServer((request, response)=> {

           let filePath = request.url;
    if (filePath == '/') {
        filePath = __dirname+'/index.html';
    }
    fileExtension= path.extname(filePath);

        fs.readFile(filePath,{encoding:"UTF-8"}, (error,content)=>{
            fileType = path.extname(filePath);
            if(!error) {
                switch (fileType) {
                    case ".css":
                        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/css"});
                        response.write(content);
                    break;
                    case ".js":
                        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/javascript"});
                        response.write(content);
                    break;
                    default:
                        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
                        response.write(content);
                }
                response.end();
            } else {
                response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
                response.write("error file");
                response.end(error);
            }
        })
    }).listen(3999);
```

Quisiera que se cargara el `HTML` y a la vez el código `JavaScript` y la hoja de estilo `CSS` que tiene incluidas (servir).

Cuando pongo en marcha el servidor aparece bien el index.html, pero los archivos `JavaScript` y `CSS` cuando lo reviso por consola, tienen en su código fuente el mismo código que el archivo `index.html`.

¿Como puedo cargar a cada archivo su respectivo contenido?, es decir: ¿Como puedo poner en marcha el servidor y servile `CSS` y `JavaScript`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para servir de `CSS` y `JavaScript` a un archivo `HTML` debes de seguir estos tres pasos:

### 1 - Crear el documento HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta></meta>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

### 2 - Incluir tus archivos CSS y JavaScript

```
 <html>
        <head>
            <meta></meta>
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
        <body>
        </body>
        <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</html>
```

### 3 - Configura tu Script de nodejs

**crearServer.js**:

```
// Incluimos los módulos necesarios

const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

// Hacemos nuestra peticion HTTP
http.createServer((request, response)=> {

// Creamos la variable que guardara la url de la petición HTTP
    let filePath = request.url;

// Por defecto sera / , debemos agregarle nuestro index.html, solo en la 
// primera petición

    if (filePath == '/') {
        filePath = '/index.html';
    }

// Seguido añadiremos la ruta de donde esta nuestro archivo y por ende 
// nuestra carpeta de la pagina web.
// Para cada petición arrojara:
//  =>  C:/usuario/carpeta/paginaWeb\index.html
//  =>  C:/usuario/carpeta/paginaWeb\css.css
//  =>  C:/usuario/carpeta/paginaWeb\javascript.js

    filePath = __dirname+filePath;

// Obtenemos la extensión del los archivos
    let fileExtension = path.extname(filePath);

// Declaramos la extensión por defecto
    let contentType = 'text/html';

// Filtramose el tipo de contenido
    switch (fileExtension) {
        case ".css":
            contentType = "text/css";
        break;
        case ".js":
            contentType = "text/javascript";
        break;
        case ".html":
            contentType = "text/html";
        default:
            contentType = "text/html";
    }

// Hacemos la lectura del archivo

   fs.readFile(filePath,{encoding:"UTF-8"}, (error,content)=>{
       if(!error) {

// Escribimos la cabecera y pasamos el tipo de contenido

           response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": contentType});
           response.write(content);
           response.end();
       } else {

 // Si hay error lo mostramos

           response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
           response.write("error file");
           response.end();
       }
       })

// Configuramos la escucha de las peticiones a un puerto determinado

   }).listen(port);
```

### 4 - Versión modular

```
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

let crearServidor = (puerto) => {
    http.createServer((request, response)=> {
        let filePath = request.url;
        if (filePath == '/') {
          filePath = '/index.html';
        }
        filePath = __dirname+filePath;
        fileExtension= path.extname(filePath);
        switch (fileExtension) {
            case ".css":
                contentType = "text/css";
            break;
            case ".js":
                contentType = "text/javascript";
            break;
            case ".html":
                contentType = "text/html";
            default:
                contentType = "text/html";
        }
        fs.readFile(filePath,{encoding:"UTF-8"}, (error,content)=>{
            if(!error) {
                response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": contentType});
                response.write(content);
                response.end();
            } else {
            response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
            response.write("error file");
            response.end();
            }
        })
    }).listen(puerto);
};

crearServidor(8888);
```

### 4 - Pon el servidor en marcha desde la consola de nodejs

```
C:\ruta\dela\web\>node crearServidor.js
```

### 5 - Visita en tu navegador el servidor

`localhost:8888`

### 6 - Servidor en Marcha

Answer (score 1):

O puedes usar express que hace todo esto por ti ;-)

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client")));
app.set("port", (process.env.PORT || 8080));
app.listen(app.get("port"));
```

Y aqui tienes todos tus ficheros html, js y css en la carpeta client